# Does Bulk 2.0 real ignores the Line Ending Header (Ignored)

Tags: bulk-api-v2

According to the offical document, the line ending header is ingored in Bulk API 2.0
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/bulk_api_2_0_line_ending_header.htm
however, my experience showed otherwise, when I tried to create a job with line ending header as "LF" and served a csv file from windows, it gives the error that line ending of the csv file is not "LF". I have checked that in windows, the line ending is "CRLF". So I created a second job with line ending header as "CRLF", this time, it worked.
So I believe that the line ending header in bulk api 2.0 actually matters.
[image]